# How can I connect button to function?

Tags: unity-game-engine

we have a dash button in the game. If we press the button dash button is working well but the problem is if we press anywhere on screen it is working too! We only want to work that function with button.
Anyone help us please?

Code:

```
public void Dash()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))

    {
        activeMoveSpeed = dashSpeed;
        dashCounter = dashLength;
    }
    if (dashCounter > 0)
    {
        canShoot = false;
        dashCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (dashCounter <= 0)
        {
            canShoot = false;
            activeMoveSpeed = speed;
            dashCoolCounter = dashCoolDown;
        }
    }
    if (dashCoolCounter > 0)
    {
        canShoot = false;
        dashCoolCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Movement();
    Dash();
}
```

[Button and Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eIIx.png)

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RriN9.png)

Comment: Your problem likely stems from checking if mouse is down that frame in the button. Split your code to doing the dash. And checking for it which would normally be in say update. Then your ui button can call the dash code anything else can call the check to dash which if satisfied would call the dash code

Comment: For some reason you are calling `Dash` in every `FixedUpdate` call and check there `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` which will be true anywhere on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you specify in `OnClick` will be called whenever the button is clicked.

Currently, you are not using the button at all. I think you meant something like this (`StartDash()` is the function that should be chosen in OnClick):

```cs
public void StartDash()
{
    activeMoveSpeed = dashSpeed;
    dashCounter = dashLength;
}

private void DoDash()
{
    if (dashCounter > 0)
    {
        canShoot = false;
        dashCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (dashCounter <= 0)
        {
            canShoot = false;
            activeMoveSpeed = speed;
            dashCoolCounter = dashCoolDown;
        }
    }
    if (dashCoolCounter > 0)
    {
        canShoot = false;
        dashCoolCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Movement();
    DoDash();
}
```

Take a look at the related pages in the Unity Documentation:

- [Manual - Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/script-Button.html)
- [Scripting - UI.Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html)
- [Scripting - UI.Button.onclick](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html)